# PHP Soap client with complex types

Tags: php, object, soap, soap-client

I am trying to get request with this structure:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:getCreditReportTypes>
    <reportTypeRequest>
      <reportParams xsi:type="ns1:personCreditReportParams">
        <personId>4</personId>
        <consentConfirmed>true</consentConfirmed>
      </reportParams>
    </reportTypeRequest>
  </ns1:getCreditReportTypes>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Here is my php-code:

```
$obj = new \stdClass();
$obj->personId = 4;
$obj->consentConfirmed = true;
$data = new \SoapVar($obj, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "personCreditReportParams", $namespace, "reportParams");
$res = $this->client->getCreditReportTypes(new \SoapParam($data,"reportTypeRequest"));
```

However, php generates invalid xml:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:getCreditReportTypes xsi:type="ns1:personCreditReportParams">
    <consentConfirmed>true</consentConfirmed>
    <personId>4</personId>
  </ns1:getCreditReportTypes>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

How can I make a valid XML with object-way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who'll get the same problem.
My solution is to use nusoap (https://github.com/yaim/nusoap-php7). This library allows you to make complicated requests, including SWA (SOAP with Attachments).
Here is working code for my question:

```
$person = array("personId"=>$id, "consentConfirmed"=>$confirmed);
$data = array(
  "reportParams"=>new soapval("reportParams", "personCreditReportParams", $person, false, $namespace)
);
$result = $client->call("getCreditReportTypes", $data, $namespace);
```

P.S. I've tried some generators and no one could make correct request, although classes were generated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitively use a WSDL to php generator such as [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator).

It'll ease you the request construction, the response handling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work. I think this is because of inheritance. PackageGenerator created abstract class reportParams and class personCreditReportParams, but it does not create <reportParams xsi:type="ns1:personCreditReportParams"> element while I pass variable of personCreditReportParams class

Comment: in this case you can always override the SoapClient object using your own implementation such in https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageEws365/blob/develop/SoapClient/SoapClient.php in order to alter the XML request before it is actually sent. Look to the generation options in https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageEws365/blob/develop/generate.sh